# Holes in Mesh, when using Subdivision Surface Modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm currently tinkering around with some Blender tutorials.

I created a lowpoly body, but when I apply a subdivision surface modifier, I get those weird artifacts/holes in my mesh.

Any idea what could be the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Select All, press W > Remove Doubles. Also get rid of ngons, Subsurf doesn't work well with them.

Comment: it's difficult to say exactly what, without having the model (you could upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then post the provided link editing your Q), only general guesses may be made: your geometry has some part wrong ...

Comment: Try selecting all in Edit mode and recalculating normals (Ctrl+N)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a loop cut right next to another.  In *Edit Mode* select all press <kbd>W</kbd> and *Remove Doubles* as LukeD suggested.

With your mouse cursor in the viewport hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> on your keyboard and click *Vertex Select Mode*.  Select loose geometry by clicking *Select* at the bottom of your viewport then *Select all by Trait* > *Loose Geometry*.

You may be able to see it on the inside of your mesh. That will need to be deleted. You'll have to put close up some holes most likely but that should fix it.  You also have some n-gons on the legs that should be turned into quads.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

maybe double verts, select everything in edit, press W, and click remove doubles, if that doesn't work i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some loop cuts to smooth out the jagged parts. So go into edit mode and hit ctrl+r. A purple circle will show up. Click and then Move the circle around and see what smooths the mesh. My guess is the problem relates to awkward geometry (so maybe flipped normals or double faces). If you accidentally misplace a loop cut just select it and hit G twice to move it. Hope that helps :).

Answer (score 1):

Go into Vertex- or Edge Select Mode, have nothing selected and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. That will select all edges that do not have exactly 2 faces attached to it and I bet you have a few of those.

Do you have any creases where you don't want them to be? They also cause the subsurf to create problems.

[image]

There's also an ngon that ideally should turn into quads.