# When subdividing holes appeared, how do you prevent this/ is there a way to fill them all at once?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[Holes in Mesh, when using Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/86478/174863)
tried options in this but they haven't worked, could this be because we have polygons not quads[image: holes that appeared after subdivision]

Comment: Select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance before subdividing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging the vertices or using the weld modifier should fix the issue.
If that doesn't work, recalculate the normals.

Comment: Please consider that beginners come to this site for help. It would improve the answer if you would explain how to merge vertices or recalculate the normals.